# Job shop scheduling variant - physical stacks of jobs (precedence constraint?) and desired output order

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, or-tools, constraint-programming

I am trying to understand the most appropriate way of framing what I believe to be a variant of the Job Shop Scheduling problem.

Key details are:

1. I have ten stacks which contain a finite number of jobs
2. I can only access the top job from each stack
3. I have two machines, jobs can only be processed by machine #1 OR machine #2 (this information is tied to the job due to specifics of the product)
4. Each machine has five stacks at its output (e.g. M1.1, M1.2, etc.). Once a job is completed, the job must be placed in one of the stacks associated with the machine that processed the job.
5. Each job is also associated with a customer - the number of customers is greater than the number of available output stacks (e.g. Customer_A, Customer_B, etc.)
6. I am trying to optimise the order of processing the jobs to group the jobs in the output stacks by customer (as much as possible, asubject to input job availability) - e.g. stack M1.1 contains all/mostly jobs for Customer_A, stack M1.2 contains mostly jobs for Customer_B on the bottom, then jobs for Customer_E stacked on top, etc.

What I am trying to understand is if linear programming/constraint programming/combinatorial optimisation is appropriate for this problem, and if so - what sort of exemplar problem I can use as a foundation.

My initial thought is that this is a Job Shop scheduling problem, however I have not been able to find any details on how to implement items 4., 5. and 6. from the above list.

I had also considered this could be more analogous to a 'container yard reshuffling' problem, however the examples I can find of this are typically targeting accessing particular containers within a stack and minimising the number of movements, rather than the constraints specified in items 2., 3. and 6.

This also may (?) be able to be formulated as a multiple knapsack problem with precedence constraints - considering the finite number of output locations (thus not appropriate for the bin stacking problem), however I am not sure how to implement the ordering optimisation (item 6.) in such a framework.

Comment: A related problem that might be worth considering is the Minimizing Open Stacks problem. See for example https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/pstuckey/papers/cp09-os.pdf